# How to load an image from local python server?

Tags: python, html, server, localhost, http-status-code-404

I am trying to learn how to use a server for website development. I do not know much Python to begin with, but it seems to be the simplest way. So far I am able to get my image resource to load when I open my index.html file directly, but when I load it over my local Python server, only the plain text is loaded to the browser.

I believe that I have written the correct HTML as it loads correctly when I open it directly from my hard drive. I think that the Python server code needs to be updated so it can understand where the image file is located. My current file structure looks like this:

projectRoot
...assets
......fonts
......images
.........mockDrawing.png
...html
......index.html
......server.py
...scripts

I have server.py in html folder because I have not yet figured out how to get it to work from the scripts folder. When I load the index.html from the server I use the following commands from the terminal:

```
$ cd projectroot/html  
$ python3 server.py
```

I then open a new tab in browser and type:

```
localhost:8080
```

This is the code in the server.py file:

```py
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is the index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is being received from a Python server</h1>
    <img src="../assets/images/mockDrawing.png" alt="Mock Drawing"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the image (which is a drawing of how I intend to make the website look eventually) to load, but so far it only displays the alt text in Firefox, and displays an '?' in Safari. Both consoles say there is a 404 error trying to find the file.

EDIT:
The output from the terminal is as follows:

```
serving at port 8080
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2019 21:22:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2019 21:22:05] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2019 21:22:05] "GET /assets/images/mockDrawing.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: I suspect that it might be because you use relative path, try to use an absolute path. Might be wrong though.

Comment: @MichaelT If by absolute path you mean from starting the src path name from the root of the hard drive then I have tried that and the result is still the same.

Comment: absolue means staring with `http://localhost:8080/`. And browser will not load images if they are not available from `localhost:8080`. It can't load images directly from disk when it gets HTML from server. Someone could create code which can steal you password, naked images, etc.

Comment: @furas when I type that into my browser (Firefox) it automatically changes it back to simply localhost:8080. Same thing happens on Safari. Do I need to specify that in the Python code?

Comment: your server can sends only files from folder `html` - so you have to put images in this folder. If you will have `home/image.jpg` on disk then you can use `<img src="http://localhost:8080/image.jpg">"` or shorter `<img src="/image.jpg">"`

Comment: if you put image in `home/asserts/image.jpg` then you can use `<img src="http://localhost:8080/asserts/image.jpg">` or shorter `<img src="/asserts/image.jpg">"`. You can't get images from `home/..` for security reason. Someone could steal your data. If you want to serve from different folder then you whould have to add more code which get images from other folders.

Comment: @furas Thank you for the help. I can now see the image after I have placed the image in the same folder, and updated the html to reflect that change. I certainly don't want to create an unsecured website, do you know of good resources to learn about how to write server code in Python or other languages?

Comment: absoluth path means you have to start urls with `http://localhost:8080/` or `/` in  HTML - `src="http://localhost:8080/image.jpg` or `src="/image.jpg"`, `url="http://localhost:8080/.other_page.html"` or `url="/other_page.html"`,

Comment: There are different servers: WWW servers, EMAIL servers, SSH servers, FTP servers, etc. I don't know resorces for any servers. People usually use existing WWW servers like `Apache`, `Nginx`, and/or Python's WWW frameworks like `Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle` which can works with `Apache`, `Nginx` or WSGI servers like `Gunicorn`, `uWSGI`. Python's WWW frameworks have also built-it servers to test it before you use with `Gunicorn`, `uWSGI`.

Comment: source about using Python to create WWW page: [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-contents.html). But there are info how use existings servers and tools, not how to built them from scratch.

Comment: there is few articles [how to build web server from scratch](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/)

Comment: @furas Thanks a bunch, I have certainly misunderstood a lot of the terminology and have a lot to learn. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from furas is right. You should move images to the path where you start the server.